# */15 cron not running for the 45th minute of the hour

Tags: php, cron

I've had a weird issue. I've set up crontab such that it runs over every 15 minutes.

```
*/15 * * * * php /var/www/index.php api/cron check_for_reminders
```

What the above crontab entry does is that it will call the file index.php and pass `api/cron` and `check_for_reminders` as parameters.

The script seems to run over the 00, 15th and 30th minute of the hour, but it fails to run at the 45th minute. Why would that happen?

```
DEV   - 2017-03-08 10:15:01 --> production
DEV   - 2017-03-08 10:15:01 --> production
ERROR - 2017-03-08 10:15:01 --> Severity: 8192  --> mysql_pconnect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead /var/www/XXXX/database/drivers/mysql/mysql_driver.php 91
DEV   - 2017-03-08 10:30:01 --> production
DEV   - 2017-03-08 10:30:01 --> production
ERROR - 2017-03-08 10:30:01 --> Severity: 8192  --> mysql_pconnect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead /var/www/XXXX/database/drivers/mysql/mysql_driver.php 91
DEV   - 2017-03-08 11:00:01 --> production
DEV   - 2017-03-08 11:00:01 --> production
ERROR - 2017-03-08 11:00:01 --> Severity: 8192  --> mysql_pconnect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead /var/www/XXXX/database/drivers/mysql/mysql_driver.php 91
DEV   - 2017-03-08 11:00:01 --> production
DEV   - 2017-03-08 11:00:01 --> production
ERROR - 2017-03-08 11:00:01 --> Severity: 8192  --> mysql_pconnect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead /var/www/XXXX/database/drivers/mysql/mysql_driver.php 91
```

Comment: Add `MAILTO="youremail@example.com` at the beginning of your cron tab. Then you should recive emails every time cron is run. Also there should be errors if any occured. I bet problem is with your PHP script

Comment: If there was an issue with the php script, then the intialization logs wouldnt have happened. Thanx for the advice btw.

Comment: Why not just be explicit about the times you want it to run?  0,15,30,45 ?

Comment: a) how is that related to php itself? b) you *really* should listen to the warnings your code produces and migrate away from `mysql`-functions.